# Sonata Admin, dependant child fields

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I have three classes,

`OrderAdmin`,  `ProductAdmin`, `OrderHasEquipmentAdmin`.

`Order` needs to add a `Product` and `Equipment` related to that product into an intermediate table `OrderHasEquipment`.

I can add a new Product, but when I try to add an OrderHasEquipment, it shows every Equipment I have in my DB, I only want to show the equipment available for that product and append to that Order.

Relations are

**Order -> manyToOne  -> Product**

**Order -> oneToMany -> OrderHasEquipment** *(because I need an intermediate Entity to work with sonata admin `sonata_type_collection` and `sonata_type_model_list`)*

**Product -> manyToMany -> Equipment**

So, when creating/editing an `Order`, it shows up a choice list with `Product`s, I need a behaviour that when a `Product` is selected, `OrderHasEquipment` (that is a `sonata_type_collection` field with `sonata_type_model_list` inside because the intermediate entity), allow me to only add an `Equipment` item related to that `Product` selected.

Any way of doing this?

Comment: Do you used ->with('Relation table')?

Comment: Now, I was trying to use child and parent stuff but doesn't work as spected. How is that `->with('Relation table')` stuff?

Comment: Do you set all right relations for OrderHasEquipment?

Comment: Yes, relations are correct, forms are working perfectly, what I want is to show only Equipments for selected Product and assing them to Order, that's the workflow I don't know how to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

If all relations right:

```
protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
    {
        $datagridMapper
            ->add('Equipment') //name from Entity
        ;
    }
```

Comment: well, you said `->with('Equipment')` before, now `add`, as I said, I can add the form field correctly, without problems, using `->add(`Equipment`)` what I can't do (because don't know how) is to get only the elements for that field that are related to `Product` within `Order`.